# "Telefon" verhält sich zu "telefonisch" wie "E-Mail" zu ...?

Tags: single-word-request, adjective, analogy

Gibt es ein ähnliches Wort wie "telefonisch" oder "postalisch", das sich jedoch auf den E-Mail-Verkehr bezieht?

> "Bei Fragen erreichen Sie mich ??? unter der obigen E-Mail-Adresse."
>
> "Sie können uns telefonisch, postalisch oder ??? erreichen."

Die geläufige Form scheint **`per Mail`** zu sein, aber die ist ja aus grammatikalischer Sicht leider nicht gleich aufgebaut. (kein Adjektiv)

Existiert ein entsprechender Begriff?

Comment: ... zu emailliert. ;)

Comment: Wenn es aus grammatikalischer Sicht gleich aufgebaut sein soll, dann kann man auch einfach schreiben: "Sie können uns per Telefon, Post oder E-Mail erreichen."

Comment: Schätze, dass man bezüglich email-Verkehr erst etwas finden muß, was beim telfonischen Kontakt dem "Telefon" entspricht. Das wäre dann eher der "Mailreader" oder z.B. "Thunderbird". Und dann wird's imho einfacher; man hätte dann passend "mailreaderisch", "thunderbirdisch" oder so. Ich könnte mir als (z.Zt. best) passendes Adjektiv auch "online" oder "digital" neben den schon genannten "elektronisch" (oder "elektrisch", wenn man einen Hauch von Ironie erlaubt) vorstellen.

Comment: Warum sollen alle drei Wörter Adjektive sein? Das verstehe ich nicht. "telefonisch, per Brief oder per e-Mail" wäre okay. postalisch klingt mir etwas gestelzt.

Comment: @rogermue: Der Einheitlichkeit halber. Die Frage ist doch eher, wieso sollte ich eine "per X" Konstruktion verwenden, wenn es ein passendes Adjektiv gibt. (Gibt es ja nun leider nicht, aber fragen kostet ja nichts. ;)

Comment: @atticae - Drei Adjektive auf -isch wie telefonisch, postalisch, elektronisch klingt für mich eher eintönig.

Comment: @rogermue: Das glaube ich dir, aber das steht hier gar nicht zur Debatte. :) Die Frage ist doch recht klar formuliert oben, ich sehe nicht wie uns diese Diskussion über den Beispielsatz weiter bringt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

“Telefon” verhält sich zu “telefonisch” wie “E-Mail” zu:

> per E-Mail

Etwas besseres kenne ich nicht, jedenfalls gibt es dafür kein Adjektiv.

Comment: Neben 'per E-Mail' hätte ich noch 'mittels ...' oder 'qua ...' zu bieten.

Answer (score 12):

Ich gebe Hubert Schölnast recht: Die übliche und eleganteste Wendung ist "per E-Mail". Allerdings findet sich auch "elektronisch", so z. B. in der Regelung der Allgemeinen Informationspflichten im §5 des Telemediengesetzes (TMG) oder auf den Webseiten verschiedener Stadtverwaltungen und Firmen:

- §5 TMG:
  http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/tmg/__5.html ("Angaben, die eine schnelle elektronische Kontaktaufnahme und unmittelbare Kommunikation mit ihnen ermöglichen, einschließlich der Adresse der elektronischen Post ...")
- Landkreis Cuxhaven:
  http://www.landkreis-cuxhaven.de/index.phtml?sNavID=1779.158&La=1 ("Elektronische Kommunikation")
- Landeshauptstadt Kiel:
  http://www.kiel.de/_impressum.php ("Elektronische Kommunikation mit der Stadtverwaltung")
- Mercedes Benz Classic: http://www.mercedes-benz-classic.com/content/classic/mpc/mpc_classic_website/de/mpc_home/mbc/home/museum/mercedes-benz-museum/visitor_information/kontakt.html ("Gerne nehmen wir Ihre Anfragen telefonisch, elektronisch sowie persönlich entgegen ...")

Weitere Beispiele finden sich über Google: [https://www.google.de/search?q=kontakt+"telefonisch"+"elektronisch"](https://www.google.de/search?q=kontakt%20%22telefonisch%22%20%22elektronisch%22)

Comment: Heutzutage sollte eigentlich jeder (sogar Stadtverwaltungen und Landkreise, Mercedes-Benz **Classic** lasse ich das mal durchgehen, die fühlen sich für Oldtimer zuständig) wissen, dass Telefone auch elektronisch funktionieren.

Answer (score 2):

Korrekt ist `per E-Mail` oder etwas kürzer `per Mail`.

Man könnte auch `elektronisch` sagen, aber das ist eher ungewöhnlich und auch nicht ganz eindeutig (Fax ist auch elektronisch, es könnte auch per ftp oder einer anderen Übertragungsart sein).

Answer (score 2):

"Bei Fragen erreichen Sie mich schriftlich unter der obigen E-Mail-Adresse."

Answer (score 0):

Ich finde ja `fernschriftlich` schön, aber wenn man's genau nimmt, gilt das nur für per Fernschreiber übermittelte Texte.

Analogon fürs Telefon hierzu ist das schöne `fernmündlich`.

Comment: Nein, "fernmündlich" kommuniziert man selbstverständlich nur mit dem Fernsprecher, nachdem man die Nummer im Fernsprechteilnehmerverzeichnis nachgeschlagen hat. :-)

Comment: Ich benutze einen *tragbaren Fernsprecher* und kein "Händi", weshalb "fernmündlich" für mich völlig in Ordnung ist. Leider enthält die 'Antwort' keinen Bezug zur Frage nach der E-Mail Kommunikation.

Comment: Laß mich raten: auf diese Seite bist du mit deinem Gewebestöberer gelangt, nachdem du dich ins Zwischennetz eingemeldet hast. Wahrscheinlich fährst du auch einen Selbstbeweger mit einem Vier-Topf-vier-Bumms-Zerknall-Treibling als Antrieb.

Answer (score -1):

"Per Mail" finde ich nicht zündend, weil hier das "e-" weggefallen ist und beim Übersetzen nur "per Post" übrig bliebe (und die Argumentation "ist doch die englische Vokabel, also muss das Internet gemeint sein" ist dann doch zu platt). Soll es ein Adjektiv sein, bleibt m. E. nur, auf die ungebräuchliche Übersetzung "e-Post" auszuweichen und analog "e-postalisch" zu bilden.